# Elasticsearch 7.10 How to give more weight to terms that appear earlier in a document

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

Let's say we issue a query (the exact type is not relevant) for the term: "cosmopolitan," on a particular field, and let's assume that the result set contains several documents which each contain exactly 'k' instances of "cosmopolitan."

By whatever mechanism is applicable (boosting, weighting, sorting, etc), I'd like the result set returned such that the positions of "cosmopolitan" within the documents is taken into account, i.e. if the average position of cosmopolitan is lower (closer to the start of the doc), then its rank/score is higher.

I've looked into different sorts of queries and scripting, but can't seem to find something that applies to this, which seems odd since for many domains the term position can be really important.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If we're talking about exact substrings of an arbitrary `myfield`, we can use a [sorting script](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/painless/current/painless-sort-context.html) which subtracts the index of first occurrence from the whole string length, thereby boosting earlier occurrences:

```
{
  "query": { ... },
  "sort": [
    {
      "_script": {
        "script": {
          "params": {
            "substr_value": "cosmopolitan"
          },
          "source": """
            def fieldval = doc['myfield.keyword'].value;
            def indexof = fieldval.indexOf(params.substr_value);
            return indexof == -1 ? _score : _score + (fieldval.length() - indexof)
          """
        },
        "type": "number",
        "order": "desc"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

The `.keyword` mapping is not required -- the field could've had the [`fielddata: true`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/text.html#fielddata-mapping-param) setting too -- either way, we'll need access to the original value of `myfield` in order for this script to work.

---

Alternatively, a [function score query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html) is a great fit here:

```
{
  "query": {
    "function_score": {
      "query": {
        "match": {
          "myfield": "cosmopolitan"
        }
      },
      "script_score": {
        
        "script": {
          "params": {
            "substr_value": "cosmopolitan"
          },
          "source": """
            def fieldval = doc['myfield.keyword'].value;
            def indexof = fieldval.indexOf(params.substr_value);
            return indexof == -1 ? _score : (fieldval.length() - indexof)
          """
        }
      },
      "boost_mode": "sum"
    }
  }
}
```

You can tweak its parameters like `boost_mode`, `weight` etc to suit your needs.

Also, you'll probably want to do some weighted avg of all the substring occurrences and you can do so within those scripts.

Comment: Thank you, that was super helpful.  I really appreciate it.

Comment: Nice, glad to hear that! Hey, I'm writing a handbook on Elasticsearch and would like to [hear your input](https://jozefsorocin.typeform.com/to/XeQRxdwV). Cheers!

Comment: NB: Unless track_scores is set to true in the top level of the request, _score will always be 0 for the sorting context script, since ES won't bother to calculate the score (it's expensive and ES assumes that you're overriding it anyway).